# Изменение повторяющихся значений в Excel

Tags: excel, дата, время, excel-формулы

Есть очень большой массив данных (44 тысячи строк) содержащих в себе дату и время в одном столбце. Но некоторые значения приходили с сервера одновременно поэтому у них одинаковые значения. Помогите написать формулу в Excel для выделения всех одинаковых значений и если значение одинаковое то сместить на одну секунду.
На скриншоте первый столбец необходим для сохранения порядка (так как данные времени идут не по порядку), во втором столбце отмечены повторяющиеся значения и уникальные.

[image: На скриншоте первый столбец необходим для сохранения порядка (так как данные времени идут не по порядку), во втором столбце отмечены повторяющиеся значения и уникальные]

Comment: После добавления секунды, может оказаться, что время совпадет с другой, несвязанной датой и придется двигать все остальное. плохой вариант.

Comment: Да, но дата будет другая, поэтому совпадения по ячейкам же не будет

Comment: Из ваших данных видно что и дата может быть та же, кроме того изменяя дату, вы как бы "подделываете" документы и эта дата становится бесполезной, на эту дату больше нельзя опереться, я бы предложил создать еще один столбец, идентификатор, соединив первый и второй столбец, и работать с ним,

Comment: Возможно, сама дата-время не имеет значения. Реализация заависит от конечной цели. @ТАННЕР, расскажете?

Comment: Основная идея избавить именно от повторяющихся значений. При следующем этапе обработки данные будут накладываться по времени, что может порушить систему. Поэтому изменение секунд не сильно повлияет на дату ибо там не так много значений каждый день.

Answer (score 0):

Развивая идею @Oopss, могу предложить обойтись просто уникальным идентификатором. "соединив первый и второй столбец" - это лишнее. После сортировки по метке времени нужно заполнить новый столбец числами по порядку.

Comment: Как раз первый столбец и есть уникальный идентификатор для каждой записи.

Comment: Но он не упорядочен по времени.

Answer (score 0):

Если диапазоны одинаковых значений неразрывны (значения расположены в соседних строках), то сортировать не нужно. Иначе подготовить данные - сделать сортировку по столбцу `B` (по возрастанию или убыванию).

В `C2` вписать формулу, копировать на весь диапазон строк:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2<>B1;B2;C1+1/86400)
```

> Для понимания. Дата в Excel - целое число (24 часа = 1). 86400 -
> столько секунд в сутках. В формуле добавляем долю суток, равную
> секунде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно заменить данные столбца `B` новыми:

- выделить диапазон с формулами, начиная с `C2`, копировать;
- выделить ячейку `B2`, ПКМ - **вставить как значения**;
- формулы можно удалить.

Вернуть предыдущий порядок строк - сортировка по столбцу `A` по возрастанию. Если при этом нужно оставить данные столбца `С` (т.е. не делать замену в столбце `B`), перед сортировкой: выделить диапазон с формулами, начиная с `C2`, копировать, ПКМ - вставить как значения.

P.S. @Tunker приметил (см. комментарий), что при наличии значений, которые отличаются незначительно, формулу нужно подкорректировать. Но тут проблема больше и корректировка не поможет. Если таких значений будет несколько, то задача в таком виде нерешаема. Пример на картинке (столбцы `C`, `D`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выход: сортировка по возрастанию и добавление к нижним совпадающим значениям большего количества секунд (столбец `E`). Но насколько это правильно?

Comment: Я бы предложил `c2=b2`, а `c3` и ниже сравнивать `b3` и `c2`, это исключит возможные совпадения времени в столбце `c` если в столбце `b` будет разница в секунду например

Comment: Дельное замечание, но предложенная реализация тоже не решает задачу: `=ЕСЛИ(B3<>C2;B3;C2+1/86400)` - некорректно обработаются диапазоны, в которых больше двух одинаковых значений.

Comment: тогда `не равно` надо заменить на `больше`, тогда точно не будет одинаковых значений

Comment: Проблема шире. Дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо, формула которую вы предложили работает)))

Comment: Если Вы о формуле в правом столбце, то благодарить нужно @Tunker ;)